# telnet to multiple destination IPs and ports from multiple sources

Tags: bash, shell

I am creating a simple script that would telnet multiple destination IPs and ports from multiple sources. I have 4 files - one that has the destination IPs, second that has ports, third one has the list of source IPs and the last one is a script that would telnet each dest. IP and port from multiple sources. So I have these files:

```
dest_ips.txt,
ports.txt,
source_ips.txt,
port_test.sh
```

I am trying something like this:

```
for s in `cat source_ips.txt`
do
    ssh $s <port_test.sh`
```

How do I input the first 2 files (dest_ips.txt, ports.txt) to this script?

Comment: `ssh` is not telnet. Please be careful with your terminology.

Comment: I am using 'ssh $s' to connect to the source ips. port_test.sh will do the rest (which includes telnet). I just somehow need the files to be fed as input to the script (port_test.sh).

Comment: Will it read the files and behave accordingly if they were local?

Comment: Yes, it will. However, to make the files locally available would be time-consuming to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, why are you separating servers and ports into separate files?

Aside from that, DO NOT use the structure you listed:

```
for s in `cat source_ips.txt`
```

Rather, use something like

```
while read s
do # . . . 
done < source_ips.txt
```

Lots of further improvements to suggest, but let's keep it simple for the moment. For more, c.f. [BashFAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

I assume the script that the `ssh` is reading will use the other files.

To answer the question you asked, how about passing them as arguments?

```
while read s
do scp dest_ips.txt ports.txt port_test.sh "$s:/tmp/"
   ssh "$s" "cd /tmp && . port_test.sh dest_ips.txt ports.txt" <&- 
done < source_ips.txt
```

Comment: I am separating it into separate files because I need to telnet each port against every destination IPs. And it is not a fixed list. Also this needs to iterate with every IPs in source_ips.txt

Somehow with while loop it is taking only the first row from source_ips.txt.

The source_ips.txt looks like this:
10.x.x.x
10.x.x.x

However, with for loop I am able to iterate through each of these IPs.
I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: I think we need to add `< /dev/null` at the end of 3rd line, which resolves the looping problem. Anyways, thanks a lot, Paul!

Comment: Sorry I didn't think of that, and you're welcome. Personal preference - just *close* stdin. Will edit accordingly.